# Separar retorno de uma tabela para uma timeline

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou criando uma timeline onde pode haver mais de uma atualização do usuário por dia.

Preciso que meu sql de retorno ja compare as datas e eu consiga separar

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_timeline JOIN responsaveis ON id_responsavel = feito_timeline WHERE  para_timeline = '".$_SESSION['id_responsavel_matricula']."' ORDER BY data_timeline ASC ";
```

estas atualizações gravam um LOG em uma tabela com o que foi alterado e a data e hora de alteração, gostaria de uma maneira que eu comparasse as alterações realizadas em no mesmo dia e colocasse a classe indicada para que a timeline apareça somente na esquerda ou somente na direita.

Na imagem eu coloquei para cada log aparecesse um de um lado e outro de outro, porem eu gostaria de comparar as datas EX: **2018-08-07** aparecesse de um lado e a **2018-08-08** aparecesse de outro e assim em diante

Para aparecer do lado esquerdo, não utiliza classe, para aparecer do lado direito coloco a classe **inverted"**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E tendo duas atualizações na mesma data? Como ficaria a mensagem? Unia as duas na mesma?

Comment: @JoãoMartins, ai ele pegaria o Order By pela hora da alteraçao

Comment: Ha, ok, então o objetivo é, neste caso, manter todos do dia 7 do lado esquerdo e do dia 8 do lado direito?

Comment: Exato, desculpe a demora para responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro busque as datas com registros:

```
  SELECT distinct data_timeline  //converter o timestamp para data (dd/mm/yyy ou outro formato apenas de dada)
   WHERE  para_timeline = '".$_SESSION['id_responsavel_matricula']."' 
ORDER BY data_timeline order by data_timeline asc;
```

após ter as datas em um array você poderá buscar todos os registros desta data.

```
 $datas = array('01/08/2018', '02/08/2018'); //resultado da query acima
 foreach($datas as $key => $data){

     //define a classe do box da timeline
     $class = $key % 2 ? '' : 'inverted'; 

     //retornar todos os registros da data 
     $sql = "SELECT * 
               FROM tb_timeline 
               JOIN responsaveis 
                 ON id_responsavel = feito_timeline 
              WHERE para_timeline  = '" .$_SESSION['id_responsavel_matricula'] . "' 
                AND data_timeline  = '" . $data . "' 
           ORDER BY data_timeline  ASC";

    //executa a query e traz os resultados da data em uma variavel ($resultados)

   //percorre os itens da tb_timeline na data atual do primeiro loop ($datas)
   foreach($resultados as $idx => $timeline){
   ?>
      <div class="<?php echo $class ?>">
         <!-- conteudo do item da timeline -->
      </div>
   <?php 
   }
}
```